# Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I don't understand why this is happening. I was doing a bit of research on other questions and I found out that you can't modify an collection while using a for loop. However, I am using an Iterator, why is it not working?

```
int counter = 0;
    int otherCounter = 0;
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    Iterator<Character> i = chars.iterator();
    for (char s : e.getMessage().toCharArray()) {
        chars.add(s);
    }
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        char s = i.next();
        if (chars.get(otherCounter + 1) == s) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (counter >= 2) {
            i.remove();
        }
        otherCounter++;
    }
```

I am getting an error on this line for some reason:
char s = i.next();

Answer (score 2):

You're adding to the collection after creating the iterator.
This throws that exception.

You need to create the iterator after you finish modifying the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is because an "enhanced for loop" as you are using it creates an `Iterator` behind the scenes.

In fact, when you write:

```
for (X x: whatever) {
    // do something with x
}
```

the "real", generated code goes something like:

```
Iterator<X> iterator = whatever.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    X x = iterator.next();
    // do something with x
}
```

And this is true if `whatever` implements `Iterable<X>` (which `List` does; in fact, any `Collection` does)

In your example, you create a `List<Character>`, create a first `Iterator<Character>` over it, and your for loop creates *another* `Iterator<Character>`, over the same list.

Note that you created the first before you modified your `List`... Hence the result. The first `Iterator`, which you reuse only afterwards, will detect that in the meanwhile, its underlying list has been modified: boom.

Comment: What you write is correct, but what bearing does it have on the question? I don't see how this explains the ConcurrentModificationException, especially as the enhanced for loop iterates over a different collection than the explicitly created iterator.